# RegisterStartupScript doesn't work with ScriptManager,Updatepanel. Why is that?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, scriptmanager

```
protected void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in rpChat.Items)
        {
            TextBox txt = item.FindControl("txtChatMessage") as TextBox;
            if (txt != null)
            {
                message[i] = txt.Text;
                i--;
            }
        }
        lblStatusChat.Text = "";
        RepeaterBind();
        string javaScript = "<script language=JavaScript>\n" + "alert('Button1_Click client-side');\n" + "</script>";

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myKey", javaScript);
    }
```

`timer_click` trigggers and update panel. And the alert message doesnt show up on timer_tick event

Answer (score 118, accepted):

When you use an UpdatePanel, then you can not call JavaScript using ClientScript  as you have tried to. You have to use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` instead.

So change your

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myKey", javaScript);
```

to

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(updatePanelId,updatePanelId.GetType(), "alert", javaScript, true);
```

Comment: I'm stuck with ASP.NET 2.0 where you can't give the panel ID so this won't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Passing the update panel ID and type is wrong, pass `this.Page` and `this.GetType()` to it, instead.

Answer (score 10):

You need to user ScriptManager class because you are register script when doing postback and using updatepanel

MSDN: [**`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558)

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript method used to add client script to a page when the control is wrapped inside an UpdatePanel.

**ASPX page**

```
<div>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDisplayDate" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
         <asp:Button ID="btnPostback" runat="server" onclick="btnPostback_Click" 
        Text="ClickMe" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

**CodeBehind Register StartUp Script**

```
protected void btnPostback_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(@"<script language='javascript'>");
    sb.Append(@"var lbl = document.getElementById('lblDisplayDate');");
    sb.Append(@"lbl.style.color='red';");
    sb.Append(@"</script>");

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btnPostback,this.GetType(), "JSCR", sb.ToString(),false);

}
```

Detail : [**Add JavaScript programmatically using RegisterStartupScript during an Asynchronous postback**](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=200)

Answer (score 9):

In my case ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript didn't work too.

Not work:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, 
  Me.GetType(), 
  String.Format("Data{0}", Me.ID), 
  "<script>alert(111);</script>", 
  False)
```

Work:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, 
  Me.GetType(), 
  String.Format("Data{0}", Me.ID), 
  "<script>alert(111);</script>", 
  False)
```

`Me` in the example is my custom control inherited from     `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart`

Comment: The additional `.Page` worked also for me for script being registered within `MasterPage`.

Answer (score 2):

It must be un little bit later but I found the soluce here http://forums.asp.net/p/1117430/5483679.aspx/1

You have to use System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock instead of Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript

Answer (score 0):

In case Page seems inaccessible from the class you are in.

```
Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
        

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page,page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), yourScriptVariable, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me.
This is worked.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(TryCast(sender, Control), Me.[GetType](), "alert", message, True)
```

I found it at

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ClientScriptRegisterClientScriptBlock-and-ClientScriptRegisterStartupScript-not-working-in-AJAX-UpdatePanel-in-ASPNet.aspx