# RegisterStartupScript not working inside an Update Panel to open file in new tab in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to open a file in new tab on click event of a link button inside gridview using  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript inside update panel, but its not working. The Code is as below :

```
       filename = Server.UrlEncode(filename);          
       string js = "<script>window.open('ViewReports.aspx?filename=" + Server.UrlEncode(filename) + "', '_newtab');</script>";           
       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1,UpdatePanel1.GetType(),"Pop up",js,true);
```

This also not working:

```
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), js, true);
```

And when I am using below code outside Update Panel it works:

```
         Type cstype = this.GetType();

        ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
        cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "dateSrpt", "<script>window.open('ViewReports.aspx?filename=" + Server.UrlEncode(filename) + "', '_newtab');</script>");
```

Comment: Which event have you added the registerStartupscript() code block? Please try adding it to the page_Prerender event.

Comment: Actually I am trying to open a file on click event of linkbutton. So this code is placed in click event of the link button. protected void lnkvwReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Try `RegisterClientScriptBlock` instead of `RegisterStartupScript`

Comment: Duplicate of [RegisterStartupScript doesn't work with ScriptManager,Updatepanel. Why is that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643578/registerstartupscript-doesnt-work-with-scriptmanager-updatepanel-why-is-that)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is  problem with your inline javascript. It doesn't work with the inline javascript. when I segregated it to the aspx page as separate javascript function and called the function inside the Registerstartupscript, It worked.

Javascript

```
function OpenPopup() {            
        window.open('PulseUserManagement.aspx', null, 'height=500, width=1100, status=no,      resizable=no, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no,location=no, menubar=no');
    }
```

CS code

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(updatepanel1, updatepanel1.GetType(), "Pop up", "OpenPopup();", true);
```

Please try like this, it works.

Comment: There is no overload of `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` that accepts 5 arguments. Why/how are you passing in updatepanel1?