# How do I execute javascript from code behind where the button inside an updatepanel

Tags: c#, javascript, fancybox

How do I execute javascript from code behind where the button inside an updatepanel

I want to open a div inside a fancybox and I am opening it from code behind
and It is working
but I want to put the button inside an updatepanel
but after that the javascript is not triggering
maybe because I am putting it inside document.ready
what else we can put the trigger in to work

html

```
<a id="various" runat="server" href="#inline" style="visibility: hidden"></a>
            <asp:Literal ID="fancyLtr" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel6" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_various").fancybox();
});
```

code behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
various.Attributes["href"] = "#inline";
fancyLtr.Text = "<script>jQuery(document).ready(function() {$(\"#ContentPlaceHolder1_various\").trigger('click');});</script>";
}
```

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Why don't you use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`?

Comment: How exactly If you can tell me?

Comment: Check the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643578/registerstartupscript-doesnt-work-with-scriptmanager-updatepanel-why-is-that

Comment: It is just taking some time until the fancybox open around 3 seconds, Can I show something until it opens, Or can I make it quicker

Comment: I would suggest that you check the `fancybox` plugin documentation then.

Comment: Can we in javascript show a loading image and make disappear when the document opens?