# Redirect to login page after session timeout without postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

In my application I can already redirect the user to the login page after 5 minutes of inactivity. But this only happened after a postback. I wanted the user to redirect to the page after 5 minutes of inactivity without doing a postback. As long as he didn't click anything (e.g. sorting) after 5 minutes he will be redirected.

By the way, I'm using update panel on my pages.

Thank you. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript do detect inactivity. 
If you're using JQuery, there's a plugin called [JQuery.idle](https://github.com/kidh0/jquery.idle)

Probably you'll need something like this.

```
    $(document).idle({
  onIdle: function(){
    // TODO: redirect to logout page.
  },
  onActive: function(){
    // TODO: maybe you don't need it.
  },
  idle: 300000 // 5 minutes then onIndle function will be called.
})
```

You also will need to register this script with your update panel using ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock or ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript. 
Somehting like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643578/registerstartupscript-doesnt-work-with-scriptmanager-updatepanel-why-is-that).

Comment: thanks for the answer, I already got a solution after browsing in the net. I use javascript function wherein the page will refresh after 5 minutes of inactivity. I think its also the same on your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Just accept one of the solutions, so people don't think your answer is still open.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use javascript**

[something like this javascript timer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12293/Auto-postback-in-ASP-NET) or other one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also use javascript based on what I have found in the net.